# edit label in viewcontroller before it is called( inside a storyboard)

Tags: iphone, ios

So im using a storyboard for my app. how can i edit a label on another viewcontroller inside the storyboard before the viewcontroller(the one with the label) is called?
thanks in advance

Comment: Are you segueing to the storyboard with the label from te current view controller?

Comment: yeah  i am '-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"scene2"]){
     lbl.text = @"test";
     }
}' didnt work. the label stayed the same

Comment: i think ive found the problem, none of my events at all are firing! i have no idea what ive done wrong

Comment: This sounds like a much bigger problem.  Are you calling a storyboard segue or manually invoking with `performSegueWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: thx for the reply i figured out the problem, each view didnt have a corresponding .h and .m file

Comment: No problem.  I've found Apple docs are a great starting point for learning the fundamentals in this area.